# Integrate / Convolution of a dirac Delta function from 0 to t

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, dirac-delta

I have a question about the convolution integral resulting due to an inverse Laplace transform. 
Considering one has a multiplication of 2 functions in the laplace Domain

$G(s) F(s)= \exp(-a s) F(s)$

To transform that into the time domain one can simply transform $G(s)$ and $F(s)$ separately, which results in the convolution integral

\begin{align}
\int_0^t \delta(t-a)f(t) \ dt &=\int_0^t \delta(t-\tau-a) f(\tau) \ d\tau
\end{align}

I am a bit confused with the boundaries. I know the identity of

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-a) f(t) \ dt = f(a)$$

In that case the boundaries are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Unfortunately in my case I integrate from $0$ to $t$, does that still results to the same solution of $f(a)$ or does that result in $f(t-a)$?

Comment: To avoid confusion, you might want to use \ cdot (without the gap between the forward slash and the string, which gives $\cdot$) for multiplication, and use $*$ only for convolutions.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it

Comment: I'm not sure how you got your result with an integral from $0$ to $t$ or where your delta function is coming from. Could you explain a little bit more?